# Janus Webrtc screen sharing without Chrome plugin and only with server Janus Gateway extension installed

Tags: webrtc, google-hangouts, screensharing

Is there any way to implement client `screen sharing` functionality using `webrtc` without mandatory `installation of any extension` as `Hangout`do? Why hangout never ask to install any extension to do screen sharing?

Comment: Yes!!! Chrome plugin is redundant. Here is the proof -> https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/screensharingtest.html

No plugin and screen share is working perfectly in demo.